# Handling a unique key Constraint Violation with powershell and SQL

Tags: powershell

I'm writing a script to insert a GUID into a SQL table. In order to stop duplicates, I have made the table GUID column unique.

So now I need to catch the violation and ignore if its a duplicate and continue the script. So write the new GUIDS but ignore the duplicates.

What would be the best way to catch and deal with the violation?

I've seen a few options on this site, but none work for me, most fail with The Catch block is missing its statement block. or other errors.

Example of the catch block I've been trying

```
catch(SqlException ex) 
{

     sqlException = ex.InnerException as System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException;

    if (sqlException.Number == 2601 || sqlException.Number == 2627)
    {
        ErrorMessage = "Cannot insert duplicate values.";
    }
    else
    {
        ErrorMessage = "Error while saving data.";
    }
}
```

and the errors:

```
At D:\Software Approval Requests\GetApprovalRequestsNew2.ps1:15 char:6
+ catch (UpdateException ex)
+      ~
The Catch block is missing its statement block.
At D:\Software Approval Requests\GetApprovalRequestsNew2.ps1:18 char:32
+     if (innerException != null && innerException.Number == 2627 ||     innerExceptio ...
+                                ~~
The token '&&' is not a valid statement separator in this version.
At D:\Software Approval Requests\GetApprovalRequestsNew2.ps1:18 char:65
+     if (innerException != null && innerException.Number == 2627 || innerExceptio ...
+                                                                 ~~
The token '||' is not a valid statement separator in this version.
At D:\Software Approval Requests\GetApprovalRequestsNew2.ps1:23 char:28
+ if (innerException != null && (innerException.Number == 2627 || innerException.N ...
```

Comment: shouldn't it be "-and" instead of || or &&?

Comment: You're using C# syntax (`||` should be `-or`, '&&` should be `-and` and none of your variable names are prefixed with `$`). Your errors aren't runtime, they're compile-time - you aren't writing valid PowerShell in the first place. Fix your syntax and see what happens.

Comment: Note that, while catching a generated error is certainly an *option*, it's generally better to make sure it doesn't happen in the first place. Adjusting your statements so they simply don't insert if the value already exists is less hacky than having to hard-code error numbers.

Comment: That's a much better idea Jeroen, I'm looking at that now instead

Comment: I'm stuck on exactly the same problem. No help anywhere on it, appears there are different incompatible exception handling syntax for powershell.